# updating a yaml file with ruby truncating spaces and adding dash

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a yaml file which contains the following data

```
:books:
  :action1:
    :book_name: name1
    :book_author: author1
    :publish_date: 2009

  :action2:
    :book_name: name2
    :book_author: author2
    :publish_date: 2016
```

I am trying to update one of the yaml file using simple ruby snippet as below

```
test = YAML::load_file('books_details.yml')
test[:book][:action1][:book_name] = "book x"
test[:book][:action1][:book_author] = "author y"
test[:book][:action1][:publish_date] = "2019"

File.open('books_details.yml', 'w') { |f| YAML.dump(test, f) }
```

this works but i get the following output

---

```
:books:
  :action1:
    :book_name: book x
    :book_author: author y
    :publish_date: 2019
  :action2:
    :book_name: name2
    :book_author: author2
    :publish_date: 2016
```

There is a --- added to the top of the file and the spaces are truncated 
Is there any other library that i could use that would not remove spaces and append --- to it??